# how to create a regex to avoid url in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I want to create regex which will not allow url to be entered in rails field input

currently i am using a regex which will not allow ":" and "/" . but some input scenarios will contain "/","." in it .

**`currently using : ^[^:\/]*$`**

Comment: Maybe something like this... https://regex101.com/r/IbkG1w/1

Answer (score 0):

It might be important to know why you want to do this in order to answer well.  But if this is all we get, I think I would go with:

```
def looks_like_uri?(string)
  maybe_uri = URI(string)
  return ['http', 'https'].include?(maybe_uri.scheme)
end
```

And expand on that - maybe with tests for valid hosts, etc.

But URLs can be many things.  ftp, gopher, file, etc.  It really depends on why you want to do this.

Comment: I want to restrict user from providing inputs like http://www.fb.com/user and www.fb.com/user . but "." is allowed in facebook